# What is wisdom? How to contemplate?

Tags: vipassana

There are 4 aspects  of satipatthana meditation. Can anyone explain how  to do the cittanupassana? Is it not merelly noting the hate, greed and delusion? Isn't it?.

Comment: You might want to check out Thera Soma's great essay on Satipatthana -- [The Way of Mindfulness: The Satipatthana Sutta and Its Commentary](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/soma/wayof.html)

Comment: If you are lucky Dhammadhatu might chime in & give you an answer. The tetrads aren't practised isolated but they happen sequentially. After the body-mind has been sufficiently calmed, rapture arises. If not clung to it, it calms to sukkha. This basically describes 'body tetrad' because especially rapture is both body-mind related. The more the object of meditation is let go off, the more refined the mind becomes.

Answer (score 1):

Many people will disagree with my answer because they wish to believe they are practising cittanupassana.

The word "anupassana" means to "watch closely" therefore cittanupassana is not "noting" because noting is thinking rather than watching.

Also, because "anupassana" means to "watch closely", there is no thinking whatsoever in the mind when cittanupassana occurs.

For example, in the practise of Anapanasati, cittanupassana is practised with full concentration, i.e., with knowing each in-breath & each out-breath.

About cittanupassana in Anapanasati, the Buddha commented:

> *I do not say that there is the development of mindfulness of breathing for one who is forgetful, who is not **fully aware**.*
>
> [*MN 118*](https://suttacentral.net/mn118/en/bodhi)

Cittanupassana occurs after the breathing has calmed & after the rapture that arises from calming breathing is also calmed.

Cittanupassana is directly knowing the quality & purity of the mind. Although during cittanupassana the mind can have **stains** of greed, hatred & delusions, these stains are not thoughts or thinking. They are the energy or mood of the stains/defilements themselves. Therefore, MN 10 says:

> And how, monks, does a monk fare along contemplating mind in the mind?
> Herein, monks, a monk knows intuitively the mind with attachment as a
> mind with attachment;
>
> he knows intuitively the mind without attachment, as a mind without
> attachment;
>
> he knows intuitively the mind with hatred, as a mind with hatred;
>
> he knows intuitively the mind without hatred, as a mind without
> hatred;
>
> he knows intuitively the mind with confusion, as a mind with
> confusion;
>
> he knows intuitively the mind without confusion, as a mind without
> confusion;
>
> he knows intuitively the mind that is contracted, as a mind that is
> contracted;
>
> he knows intuitively the mind that is distracted, as a mind that is
> distracted;
>
> he knows intuitively the mind that has become great, as a mind that
> has become great;
>
> he knows intuitively the mind that has not become great, as a mind
> that has not become great;
>
> he knows intuitively the mind with (some other mental state) superior
> to it, as a mind with (some other mental state) superior to it;
>
> he knows intuitively the mind with no (other mental state) superior to
> it, as a mind with no (other mental state) superior to it;
>
> he knows intuitively the mind that is composed, as a mind that is
> composed;
>
> he knows intuitively the mind that is not composed, as a mind that is
> not composed;
>
> he knows intuitively the mind that is freed, as a mind that is freed;
>
> he knows intuitively the mind that is not freed, as a mind that is not
> freed.
>
> [MN 10](https://suttacentral.net/mn10/en/horner)

Comment: In practice  of meditation experience the hate comes with memory and  when look into it is as coming  from deluted self hatred goes away. Is it correct  practice?Now experience shallow breathing  during  meditation, so meditative object cease very often the look feeling of body it feels  as rock.

Comment: As breathing lengthens, immersion deepens. Whatever phenomena are experienced in that immersion are  impermanent. Instead of classifying contacts as "self-hatred", etc., simply let go before contact, not after:
> [MN64:10-12.4](https://suttacentral.net/mn64/en/sujato#mn64:10-12.4): They contemplate the phenomena there as impermanent

Comment: Oya. your comment contradicts my answer.

Comment: when hate comes with memory, this is called a "hindrance" rather than "cittanupassana'. Even when you "when look into it is as coming from deluted self hatred & it goes away", this "wise reflection" is not "cittanupassana". YES, this "wise reflection" is the correct practice to overcome hindrances. But it is not cittanupassana. Kind regards

Comment: While  I was meditating deluted self could not being  noticed. I have not meditate for a long time after that happened. Now it just noting  the hatred it disappeared soon I noticed. It is not wise reflection. What  was it ?